# I am hunting a way to open an Access Report using a variable string.

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a drop down box which will select the specific report name 
for example tbl1Report or tbl2Report etc...- then I want to use the report name from the drop down box to open that specific report (which will be different for each record)

DoCmd.openreport "dropdownboxreportname"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Get the value of Combobox control and pass it to the `DoCmd.OpenReport`:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport Me.YourComboControlName.Value, acViewNormal, , , acWindowNormal
```